# get ItemsCount in GridEx MultiColumnCombo

Tags: multiple-columns, gridex

I just want to get Total Items in GridEx MultiColumnCombo, just like combobox1.Items.Count in Windows Forms ComboBox component...

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably no longer needed but I'll post this for anyone else that may need it...

To get the amount of items in a `MultiColumnCombo` you can use the following:

```
myMultiComboList.DropDownList.RowCount
```